# Web Access Properties of a Notes View don't appear in Source Control

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I have an NSF that is worked on by a number of developers in Domino Designer.  It is set up for source control using SourceTree/GIT.  In Domino Designer, preferences, source control, the option "Use Binary DXL" is deselected, as are the automatic sync options.

It has a basic view that is enabled for Domino Data Server Operations.  I have checked the box on the Advanced Properties of the view and it works when I query it.

[image: View Properties, Advanced Tab Dialogue Window]

When changes are made to the view, and these are committed to source control the value for "Allow Domino Data Services" is never exported, which means that when we deploy to production, some important parts of the design don't get deployed.

I have had a check of some of the other options in that tab and some of them don't seem to produce any changes in the On Disk Project in Source Control e.g. "Allow Web Crawler Indexing".

This behaviour is the same whether we use R10 or R11.  We don't have an R9 installation to test.

Does anyone know if there is a setting to change to include these flags?

Comment: This is why binary DXL exists: to allow you to export everything, including the things that the HCL (previously IBM) team never bothered to define tags or options for in the DXL doctype definition.

Comment: That's good to know Richard.  Thanks for the heads up.  We have changed to using Binary DXL now as we are trading off the readability of changes to having the changes honoured across each NSF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a quick test but I get the same results unfortunately.

In non-binary DXL there apparently is no equivalent for that setting and the others you tested. I can see that that's bad when you're working in a team.

Only alternative I can think of is to stop using DDS and switch to the closest alternative: an XPage with the ExtLib REST control on it. From the top of my head the output of that is pretty much the same if you enable the default columns.

Comment: Hi Mark.  Thanks for this.  We have kept the design as is and switched source control to binary dxl.  The DDS is for read only operations.  We may revisit this in the future though.

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to assume that when that code is pulled down by another developer that the flag is not checked?  I've been out of domino development for a while but I do recall seeing similar behavior to properties when the metadata file (I forget what it is called) is not pushed up along with the main design element.  Typically we would not push up that file unless it was a new design element but in some cases we had to if a property changed.

A shot in the dark - I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Adam, but the View doesn't seem to have a separate metadata file with it, it all appears to be in the .view file.  I'd need to check back to an r( install to see if this happened before the changes to Source Control in 10/11.

Answer (score 0):

If you use swiper, it clear $webFlags fields.